# Missing links in crossword

Tags: crosswords

> 1. Feast,  jelly,  runner (4)
> 2. circle,  fancy,  rehearsal (5)
> 3. get,  press,  streets (5)
> 4. house,  singer, soap (5)

Answer (score 9):

Your missing links are as follows:

*Feast, jelly, runner (4)*

> **BEAN** - [bean-feast](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bean-feast), jelly bean, runner bean.

*circle, fancy, rehearsal (5)*

> **DRESS** - dress circle, fancy dress, dress rehearsal.

*get, press, streets (5)*

> **AHEAD** - get ahead, press ahead, streets ahead.

*house, singer, soap (5)*

> **OPERA** - opera house, opera singer, soap opera.